# String matching with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find match in string with regular expression but is not working.
I want to match occurence of `function gcb_process`.

This is what I did:

```
$gatewayname = basename($path, ".php");
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
$searchname = $gatewayname . "_process";

preg_match("/function\s*".$searchname."/i", $contents, $matches);
```

I always get a warning:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 11

How is this done?

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with the PHP code you show here. You need to show us the code where you call `preg_match_all()`, not `preg_match()`.

Comment: I actually used preg_match_all and not preg_match

Comment: *"This is what I did:"* `preg_match("/function\s*gcb_process/i", $contents, $matches);`

Comment: You need to show us **exactly** the code that you ran, plus **exactly** the error messages you get.  Otherwise, we cannot help you.  Paraphrases and summations do not count.

Comment: just a note, it's `\s+` and not `\s*`, because there will be at least one whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested:**

```
$subject = "I want to match occurence of function gcb_process.";
$pattern = '/function gcb_process/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => function gcb_process )
```

Read [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) more details

Comment: Ok, I wasn't getting the correct value in $gateway I was getting *. $searchname was therefore "*_process and hence the error.

Comment: Can you tell us $searchname value, You can echo $searchname; to get. So that we can have some better idea

Comment: $searchname value is filename without php extension. In this case gcb.php. My gateway has filename prepended to _process. I was actually able to detect the error and working now. $gatewayname wasn't getting the right value. Thanks all.